# Why all my colors light up at once in Simon Game

Tags: javascript

HTML BODY PART

```
  <body>
      
    <div class="main">
      <img class="red" src="red.png" alt="">
      <img class="blue" src="blue.png" alt="">
      <img class="green" src="green.png" alt="">
      <img class="yellow" src="yellow.png" alt="">

      <div class="btn">
        <button class="play">Play</button>
        <button class="restart">Restart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS PART

```
const play=document.querySelector(".play")
const restart=document.querySelector(".restart")

let items=['red','blue','green','yellow']
let sequence=[]

let generateRandomSequence=()=>{
    let count=Math.trunc(Math.random()*4)
    sequence.push(items[count])
    console.log(sequence)
}


let makeColorBright=async (array)=>{
       let second=()=>{
        for(item of array){
            console.log(item)
                document.querySelector(`.${item}`).style.filter="brightness(2)"
            setTimeout(()=>{
                document.querySelector(`.${item}`).style.filter="brightness(1)"
            },2000)
        }
    }
        return second()
}


play.addEventListener("click",async function(){
    generateRandomSequence()
    await makeColorBright(sequence)
})
```

So the generateRandomSequence() function is working fine , and it adds random items in sequence everytime when I press play . My goal was to initially just see if I can make random blocks light up for which I've used sequence array. Now makeColorBright() will take inputs from sequence and the goal is to make a color light up and then wait 2 secs before it lights down , and then move onto next color. But the issue is it works fine for only one element in Sequence array. When there are 2 or more elements in sequence , all the colors light up simultaneously , but only the last element lights down after 2 secs.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `for(item of array){` to `for (let item of array) {` to narrow the scope of the `item` variable. However, even after fixing that, I don't think the script will work as expected since you call `setTimeout` in succession, without waiting.

There are a few ways to fix. Here's one that creates a timeout function using Promises.

(Note: I changed the images to divs and brightness to opacity to facilitate creating a code snippet).

```js
const play = document.querySelector(".play");
const restart = document.querySelector(".restart");

let items = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
let sequence = [];

let generateRandomSequence = () => {
  let count = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 4);
  sequence.push(items[count]);
}

// Sleep function
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function makeColorBright(array) {
  for (let color of array) {
    await wait(500)
      .then(() => document.querySelector(`.${color}`).style.opacity = 1);
    await wait(1500)
      .then(() => document.querySelector(`.${color}`).style.opacity = .2);
  }
}

play.addEventListener("click", async function() {
  generateRandomSequence();
  makeColorBright(sequence);
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: .2;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
  <div class="box green"></div>
  <div class="box yellow"></div>

  <div class="btn">
    <button class="play">Play</button>
    <button class="restart">Restart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used await/async very much, Johnny's answer may be better than my solution, but it triggers your lights in a timed succession like you wanted. You had a timeout on turning the lights off, but not when they turn on.

```js
const play=document.querySelector(".play")
const restart=document.querySelector(".restart")

let items=['red','blue','green','yellow']
let sequence=[]

let generateRandomSequence=()=>{
    let count=Math.trunc(Math.random()*4)
    sequence.push(items[count])
    console.log(sequence)
}



 doThing = async(item, t)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
                document.querySelector(`.${item}`).style.filter="brightness(2)";
        
        setTimeout(()=>{
                        document.querySelector(`.${item}`).style.filter="brightness(1)";
        }, 1000);
    }, t);
}



play.addEventListener("click",async function(){
    generateRandomSequence()

    let t = 0;
    for(item of sequence){
        doThing(item, t*1000);
      t++;
    }
    
})
```

```css
img{width:50px;height:50px}
.red{background:red;}
.blue{background:blue;}
.green{background:green}
.yellow{background:yellow}
```

```html
<div class="main">
      <img class="red" src="red.png" alt="">
      <img class="blue" src="blue.png" alt="">
      <img class="green" src="green.png" alt="">
      <img class="yellow" src="yellow.png" alt="">

      <div class="btn">
        <button class="play">Play</button>
        <button class="restart">Restart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```